# Magento2 admin When trying to create sub category it is redirecting to dashboard

Tags: magento2

Magento2 admin When trying to create sub category it is redirecting to dashboard. Not able to see any errors etc..

I think it is related to server settings as it is working fine in local but not on stage. Please guide me what server settings I should ask server team to check

Comment: I believe that would throw some error message in application or server logs. Check that & edit your question with the concrete error so we can help

Comment: There is not there. Can you share some idea to debug it